# Check if polynomials are increasing in a root neigborhood

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have proven that for $x>0$, polynomials $p(x)=\sum a_i x^i$ with positive coefficients are strictly increasing. And still strictly increasing with at least one root $x_p>0$ when $a_0<0, a_i>0, i=1..n$.

Now, most of our polynomials have this structure:
$$
a_0=-1, |a_i|<1/n, i=1...n, x>0, x_p>0 \text{ root of } p(x)
$$

I have found that for those conditions, the polynomials are still strictly increasing at the neighborhood of at least one root $x_p$. But I have been unable to prove it or find a counterexample.

All my optimization runs lead to an increasing polynomial, or to $|a_i|$ greater than 0.5 (?) breaking the constraints, such as this, with $x_p=0.909, n=10$ and (note the structure?):
$$
a=\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}[-1 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.0013 & -0.5 & -0.5 & -0.5 & -0.5]\end{array}
$$

Comment: If $p(0)$=-1, the polynomial $p(x)$ will be strictly increasing at the smallest positive root that is not also a local maximum. If $p(x)$ has only one positive root, and that root is also a local maximum, $p(x)$ would be a counterexample. An approximate counterexample appears to be $p(x)=-1 + x - {x^2\over5} + {x^3\over3.5} - {x^4\over4.824082859}$.

Comment: As you show, $|a_1|=1$, violating the fact that the leading terms are smaller. As you see, it is actually enough to show that a double root exists, for $|a_i|, i>0$ being smaller than $1/n$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit after seeing comments**: Okay this is what I understand the question asks:

Given $P(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_i x^i$ where $a_0 = -1$ and $|a_i| \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $i > 0$. Show that:

If $\exists$ a positive real root of $P(x)$ then there is some positive root of $P(x)$ s.t. $P(x)$ is non-decreasing in a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

**Ans**:

$P(0) < 0$. Two cases:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} P(x) = \infty$: By IVP, there exists a positive root of $P(x)$. Let $S$ be the set of all positive roots of $P(x)$. Then $S$ is non-empty and finite. Let $x_0 = \max_{x \in S} x$. Then if $P'(x_0) < 0$, as $P'$ is countinuos there exists a neighbourhood around $x_0$ for which $P'(x) < 0$, which implies by MVT that for some $x' > x_0$, we have $P(x) < 0$. But this is a contradiction, as this by IVP implies that there is some positive root of $P(x)$ greater than $x_0$ contradicting the maximality of $x_0$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} P(x) = -\infty$ : This case gives a counterexample, when there is a single double root.

**Note**: As you can see by the proof, the constraints $|a_i| \le \frac{1}{n}$ don't really matter.

Comment: The $a_i$ coefficient shall lead the $x^i$ term

Comment: I tried that definition. This path so far have not giving me any clue on why if I pass from "positive" into "small negative" terms I still keep a strictly increasing polynomial at the root.

Comment: The given examples do not have positive roots, without neighborhoods to check for. I have edited the original to manifest this requirement.

Comment: @Brethlosze Edited.

Comment: This is correct, we know that for $a_0=-1, p \to \infty$ we will have at least more than one root. Also we had counterexamples. But we have found no counterexamples with a $p'<0$ root and smaller $|a_i|, i>0$ coefficients. We know *at least* means, at least two.